# Can I "browse" a csv file without storing all the data in a variable?

Tags: javascript, csv, web-applications

I am working on web app in Javascript and I need to read a csv file, find some interesting data and store it.

The problem is that my csv file has 400 000 rows. Currently, I am just using the split method and storing all that data in a variable.

I am new to Javascript and I wonder if there is a better way to do it, for example if I can read a csv file without storing the whole content to a variable.

That csv file contains data from wireshark. In my app I want to scan user input (time in sec), store it in variable and find rows in the csv file containing this time.

Thanks.

Comment: You will find this interesting https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Streams_API/Using_readable_streams